# OrderBy Statement for Subfields on Firebase in Flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of following;

[image: firebase]

I want to return every company in ascending order by `companyName` and this is how I'm trying;

```
QuerySnapshot usersComp = await _firestore
        .collection('companies')
        .where('belongsTo', isEqualTo: curruser.uid)
        .orderBy({
      'properties': {'companyName'}
    }, descending: false).getDocuments();
```

Code doesn't give any errors but it also doesn't return any value as well. The statement without `orderBy` works fine.

How can I write a this `orderBy` in a working way?

**edit**

This is the whole `getCompanies` function in `FirebaseCrud`:

```
Future<List<Company>> getCompanies() async {
    FirebaseUser curruser = await _authService.getCurrentUser();

    DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .document(curruser.uid)
        .get();

    List partners = userSnapshot.data['partners'];
    print('partners');
    print(partners[0]);

    QuerySnapshot usersComp = await _firestore
        .collection('companies')
        .where('belongsTo', isEqualTo: curruser.uid)
        //.orderBy('properties.companyName', descending: false) // code works fine without this line but not as expected
        .getDocuments();

    List<Company> companies = new List<Company>();

    usersComp.documents.forEach((f) {
      int indexOfthis = usersComp.documents.indexOf(f);

      companies.add(new Company(
        uid: partners[indexOfthis],
        companyName: f.data['properties']['companyName'],
        address: f.data['properties']['address'],
        paymentBalance: f.data['currentPaymentBalance'],
        revenueBalance: f.data['currentRevenueBalance'],
        personOne: new Person(
            phoneNumber: f.data['properties']['personOne']['phoneNumber'],
            nameAndSurname: f.data['properties']['personOne']
                ['nameAndSurname']),
        personTwo: new Person(
            phoneNumber: f.data['properties']['personTwo']['phoneNumber'],
            nameAndSurname: f.data['properties']['personTwo']
                ['nameAndSurname']),
      ));
    });

    return companies;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dot notation to reference properties of objects to use for sorting.

```
_firestore
    .collection('companies')
    .where('belongsTo', isEqualTo: curruser.uid)
    .orderBy('properties.companyName'),
    descending: false)
```

Comment: This is what i wrote but didnt work http://hizliresimyukle.com/images/2020/01/14/image.png

Comment: I just quickly tested and can order on nested fields with Doug's notation: `Firestore.instance.collection("59739861").orderBy("properties.companyName").getDocuments()`. I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but you might want to update your question with the up-to-date code, including how you handle the results.

Comment: I also tested with a condition and ordering, and that also runs fine once I add the index. Before adding the index it fails with a very explicit error message, so all expected behavior. `Firestore.instance.collection("59739861").where("location", isEqualTo: "Bay Area").orderBy("properties.companyName").getDocuments()`

Comment: Hey Frank, I updated the question with the whole function.

Comment: Oividios, if you want to notify someone of your comment, you should at-mention their name like this: @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Sorry, I tried various ways and the results always come back in order. I'll post my code and output in an answer, just in case that helps.

Comment: It'd be nice for me. I'm also not sure why this problem happens. According to the tree, it should work but `QuerySnapshot` never returns with data when `OrderBy` is added.

Answer (score 1):

I created a collection with a few documents, each have a top-level field and a nested field. If I then run a query over it like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection("59739861")
    .where("location", isEqualTo: "Bay Area")
    .orderBy("properties.companyName", descending: false)
    .getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
      print("Got ${querySnapshot.documents.length} documents");
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((doc) {
        print("${doc.documentID}: ${doc.data['properties']}");
      });
    });
```

I have added these three documents in my database:

- location: "Bay Area", properties.companyName: "Google"
- location: "Bay Area", properties.companyName: "Facebook"
- location: "Seattle", properties.companyName: "Microsoft"

With the above query, I get the following output printed:

> flutter: KJDLLam4xvCJEyc7Gmnh: {companyName: Facebook}
>
> flutter: TMmrOiKTYQWFBmJpughg: {companyName: Google}

I have no idea why you're getting different output.

Just in case it matters, I run the app in an iOS simulator and use this version of the Firestore plugin:

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess it doesn't work for me for some other reason that I can't figure out right now...

Comment: I highly recommend trying to reproduce in a similar way that I did here. There's a lot more going on in the code you shared than in what I did, and the problem might well be in those additional parts. This is why it's recommended to try and reproduce the problem from scratch with as little code as possible. You'll often find the problem is completely elsewhere from where you've been looking.